# determine the frame id/name when a user has selected text in that frame- the page has multiple frames

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame

I have a scenario in which there are multiple iframes/frames open in one web page. Now user may select some text in any one of the open frames/iframes. I want to determine the id/name of the iframe in which user has selected text, using the iframe id/name I will then do some operations on the selected text.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the first iframe in the curent document that has a non-empty selection. If an iframe is from another domain and hence inaccessible to JavaScript running in the current document, the selection cannot be retrieved and the iframe is ignored.

```
function getSelectedText(win) {
    var sel;
    if (win.getSelection) {
        return "" + win.getSelection();
    } else if ( (sel = win.document.selection) ) {
        if (sel.type == "Text") {
            return sel.createRange().text;
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function getIframeWithSelection(win) {
    var iframes = win.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length, selectedText; i < len; ++i) {
        try {
            selectedText = getSelectedText(iframes[i].contentWindow);
            if (selectedText != "") {
                // alert just there for debugging
                alert(selectedText);
                return iframes[i];
            }
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    return null;
}

// Example
var iframe = getIframeWithSelection(window);
```

Comment: this is a good solution if only Arvind did some searching and found your tim-down's other answer witch is much based on the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471759/how-to-get-selected-text-from-iframe-with-javascript

Comment: @TimDown- I am trying to use your function (as given above) in a google chrome extension- the problem is that in that extension, your function is loaded into a 'background page'. Is there some way to specify the window (within which iframes have to be checked?)... Maybe pass the title of that main window as a parameter to your function, so that your function then looks for iframes in the window which has specified title? Or some other way? Thanks...

Comment: @Arvind: I've done nothing with Chrome extensions, but there was a small error in the code, which I've now corrected: it now looks for iframe elements only within the window specified (`win`). Does that help?

Comment: @TimDown- I changed the chrome extension- i used the js file containing your code as part of a content script (this is injected directly into the page)- that did the work I wanted... Thanks!