# How to choose a specific window based on its title

Tags: javascript, window

I want to choose a specific window, and perform operations on that window- I will pass that window as a parameter to another function which does the work...

I know beforehand, that the title of the windows is (for example) "XYZ"

How do I select the window in browser with that title?

I found that in javascript there are ways to assign a title to a window, but I couldnt find a way to search for and find the window which has a specific title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot select other windows, unless you've already got a reference to it.

There are two methods to get a reference:

- The `window.opener` property holds a reference to the window which opened the current one.
- Saving the return value of `window.open()` also offers a reference.

Each reference to another window will be a `window` object. `window.document.title` can be used to read the value of the title.  (where `window` is the reference to the other window).

[Cross-domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions will prevent other windows from being read, though.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807510/determine-the-frame-id-name-when-a-user-has-selected-text-in-that-frame-the-pag/7807887#7807887) to read the document/window object of embedded frames.

Comment: I plan to use this application with Same Origin Policy disabled - the problem is that the js code is loaded into a background page... So I need some way to get a reference to the window (for which I have the title with me)...

Comment: Also, how to get a reference to the current window? That would also be very helpful for me... Thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: @Arvind The current window can be referenced through `window`. The real window of the current (framed) page can be read using `top`.